# При вызове аргумент функции выдает ошибку

Tags: python, python-3.x

number_served числового типа данных. При попытке его вывести с помощью new_restaurant.number_served() выдает ошибку, что невозможно вызвать int обьект.

```
class Restaurant:
    """Create easy restaurant model"""
    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
        """Create attributes"""
        self.restaurant_name = restaurant_name
        self.cuisine_type = cuisine_type
        self.number_served = 0

    def describe_restaurant(self):
        """Describe restaurant"""
        print(f"\nRestaurant name: {self.restaurant_name}.")
        print(f"Cuisine type: {self.cuisine_type}")

    def open_restaurant(self):
        """Say about restaurant open"""
        print(f"Restaurant {self.restaurant_name} status: open!")

    def closed_restaurant(self):
        """Say about restourant closed"""
        print(f"Restaurant {self.restaurant_name} status: closed!")

    def set_number_served(self, number):
        """Change number served"""
        self.number_served = (number)

    def incriment_number_served(self, number):
        """Incriment number served"""
        self.number_served += number

new_restaurant = Restaurant("Atomix", "Chinese")

new_restaurant.describe_restaurant()
new_restaurant.set_number_served(4)
new_restaurant.number_served()
```

Comment: правильно пишет. Число невозможно вызвать. Что вы ожидаете от сией операции? Выводят с помощью print(). Разберитесь чем функция (как написано в заголовке, неправильно!) отличается от числового типа данных (как написано в вопросе, правильно).

Comment: self.number_served = (number) - тут скобки не нужны

Answer (score 0):

Я полагаю, Вы пытаетесь обратиться к аттрибуту класса под названием number_served. Однако Вы ставите `()`, которые испольуются для вызова методов класса. Код получает четверку после обращения к `new_restaurant.number_served`, а затем пытается "вызвать метод", но тип данных `int` not callable (не вызываемый), поэтому код падает. Чтобы решить проблему достаточно исправить последнюю строчку:

```
print(new_restaurant.number_served)
```